# EXPO React Native Send form data to Node JS backend

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

So I am trying to send form data using fetch API in React Native. I am new to React Native. I have worked with React JS and used fetch library to send data I am using it now to send data in Native Expo but I am unable to send data I receive nothing in return.

Front end code:

```js
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity, KeyboardAvoidingView, Image } from 'react-native';
import { Button, TextInput } from 'react-native-paper';

// <View style={styles.container}>
const SignupScreen = (props) => {

  const [name, setName] = useState('');
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const [organization, setOrganization] = useState('');
  const [role, setRole] = useState('');
  const [country, setCountry] = useState('');
  const [intro, setIntro] = useState('');

  sendCredentials = () => {
    fetch("http://192.168.0.102:3000/signup", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      body:JSON.stringify( {
        "name": name,
        "email": email,
        "password": password,
        "country":country,
        "organization":organization,
        "role":role,
        "intro": intro
      })
    })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
        console.log(data)
      })

  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.mainD}>
      <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior="position">

        <StatusBar style="light" backgroundColor="black" barStyle="light-content" />
        <Image style={styles.logoStyle} source={require('../assets/logoBlack.png')} />

        <Text style={styles.intro}> Create Account.</Text>
        <Text style={styles.subIntro}>Sign up to get started!</Text>


        <TextInput style={styles.textInpStyle} theme={{ colors: { primary: "red" } }}
          label="Name" mode="flat" value={name} onChangeText={(text) => setName(text)} />
        <TextInput style={styles.textInpStyle} theme={{ colors: { primary: "red" } }}
          label="Email" mode="flat" value={email} onChangeText={(text) => setEmail(text)} />
        <TextInput style={styles.textInpStyle} theme={{ colors: { primary: "red" } }}
          label="Password" mode="flat" secureTextEntry={true} value={password} onChangeText={(text) => setPassword(text)} />
        <TextInput style={styles.textInpStyle} theme={{ colors: { primary: "red" } }}
          label="Organization" mode="flat" value={organization} onChangeText={(text) => setOrganization(text)} />
        <TextInput style={styles.textInpStyle} theme={{ colors: { primary: "red" } }}
          label="Role" mode="flat" value={role} onChangeText={(text) => setRole(text)} />
        <TextInput style={styles.textInpStyle} theme={{ colors: { primary: "red" } }}
          label="Country" mode="flat" value={country} onChangeText={(text) => setCountry(text)} />
        <TextInput style={styles.textInpStyle} theme={{ colors: { primary: "red" } }}
          label="Into" mode="flat" value={intro} onChangeText={(text) => setIntro(text)} />
        <Button style={styles.btnStyle} mode="contained" onPress={() => sendCredentials()}>
          SIGN UP
  </Button>
        <TouchableOpacity>

          <Text style={styles.subText} >I'm already a member <Text onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate("login")} style={styles.spIn}> Sign In</Text> </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>


      </KeyboardAvoidingView>

    </View>
  );
}
```

Backend code:

```js
router.post("/signup", (req, res) => {
  const { name, email, password, country, organization, role, intro, pic } = req.body
  if (!email || !password || !name) {
    return res.status(422).json({ error: "Please add all the fields" })
  }
  User.findOne({ email: email })
    .then((savedUser) => {
      if (savedUser) {
        return res.status(422).json({ error: "User Already Exists" })
      }
      bcrypt.hash(password, 12)
        .then(hashedpassword => {
          const user = new User({
            email,
            password: hashedpassword,
            name,
            pic,
            country,
            organization,
            role,
            intro
          })
          user.save()
            .then(user => {
              res.json({ message: user.name + ' joined BigBrains' })
            })
            .catch(err => {
              console.log(err)
            })
        })

    }).catch(err => {
      console.log(err)
    })
})
```

I have tested my backend logic using Postman and backend of my program is running fine on web which I recently deployed but I am having trouble with Native.

Comment: Are you receiving some error messages? Are you running the code on one real device or using one emulator?

Comment: `sendCredentials` function should be `Asynchronous` here... So according to me it should be `const sendCredentials = async () => {  ...YOUR FETCH LOGIC HERE }`

Comment: @JancerLima I am testing it on iOS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's needed to convert the JSON object into a string with stringify.
Try to remove the stringfy function and use bodyParser on your server. that way you sending an actual object and destruct the data from it as excepted